# Spark Scala API: No typeTag available in spark.createDataFrame in official example

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I just started working with the MLib for Spark and tried to run the provided examples, more specifically https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/DCTExample.scala

However, compilation using the IntelliJ IDE fails with the message

```
Error:(41, 35) No TypeTag available for (org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector,)
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(data.map(Tuple1.apply)).toDF("features")
```

The project setup uses jdk1.8.0_121, spark2.11-2.1.0 and scala 2.10.6.

Any ideas on why the example fails to run? I followed the following tutorial during installation: https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/intellij-scala-spark/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have spark for Scala 2.11 (that's what `_2.11` in the name means) with Scala 2.10, though this specific error looks quite strange. Switch to Scala 2.11.8.

Comment: thanks, that actually fixed the issue. With the standard current release (2.12) the code was broken too, thats why I tried it with 2.10. I downloaded and installed the 2.11.8 release and the project compiles correctly.